# Dispatch_async after dataTaskWithRequest

Tags: ios, swift

In my app user taps on marker and I need to call to web service in order to get info to show. I use NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest and then call dispatch_async on main queue in order to show user the marker. But I get an error trying to pass arguments in dispatch_async

The code is following

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://78.27.190.58:3300/api/get_location_ratings")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "org_id=\(marker.userData["orgId"] as! Int)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

        data, response, error in

        var json = JSON(data: data!)

        var rating = json["results"]["avg_stars"].doubleValue

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { (mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! in

            self.window = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("infoWindow", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! infoWindow

            self.window?.name.text = marker.title
            self.window?.adress.text = marker.snippet
            self.window?.stars.image = UIImage(named: "\(showStars((marker.userData["Rating"] as! NSString).doubleValue))")
            self.window?.rating.text = String((marker.userData["Rating"] as! NSString).doubleValue)

            return window


        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

The error is

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check my new answer. My previous answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your `dispatch_async` you're using a closure with two parameters (`mapView` and `marker`), but not passing anything to those parameters.

Comment: @vien gave you the answer. You already have those variables from the function, you don't need them at all.

Comment: doesn't work that way. complains about "unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `dataTaskWithRequest`, you can't straight return value. So you have to use closure in this case. You can change code to this:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!, completion:(UIView!) -> Void)  {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://78.27.190.58:3300/api/get_location_ratings")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "org_id=\(marker.userData["orgId"] as! Int)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

        data, response, error in

        var json = JSON(data: data!)

        var rating = json["results"]["avg_stars"].doubleValue

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            let view = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)

            self.window = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("infoWindow", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! infoWindow

            self.window?.name.text = marker.title
            self.window?.adress.text = marker.snippet
            self.window?.stars.image = UIImage(named: "\(showStars((marker.userData["Rating"] as! NSString).doubleValue))")
            self.window?.rating.text = String((marker.userData["Rating"] as! NSString).doubleValue)

            completion(window)


        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

And use it:

```
your_instace.mapView(mapview, markerInfoWindow: GMSMakre) { (view: UIView!) -> Void in
        //do somethinghere
    }
```